# ODE Integrating factor question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $M(x,y) + N(x,y) \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ = 0 has an integrating factor that is a function of y alone provided

$  \displaystyle  \frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}$ is a function of y alone. What first order linear (or seperable) equation do you  solve to find this integrating factor?

Comment: you don't differentiate, you just assume that there is some function of $y$ that get's factored from exact equation.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that, also i'm a bit confused because I thought for any integrating factor for a exact transformation is e^R(x)dx, thus, always resulting in a function with x.

Comment: can be found here in [detail](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html).

Comment: $e^{\int   \displaystyle  \frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}dy}$ is the integrating factor. This is derived in most books. See Zill and Cullen for example.

Comment: Thank you, my book did not explain this concept well.

Answer (score 0):

If the differential equation 
$$ 
b(y ) M(x,y) \,dx + b(y) N(x,y)  \,dy = 
$$
is exact, then 
$$
\partial_x \; b(y)N(x,y)=\partial_y\, b(y)M(x,y)
$$
Then
$$
b(y)N_x=b'(y)M+bM_y
$$
Or equivantly
$$
\frac{b'(y)}{b(y)}=\frac{N_x-M_y}{M}
$$